# Something very strange going on in a closed question

Tags: bug, closed-questions, locked-question

Can someone have a look at [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-do-data-types-in-computers-exist-if-its-really-all-just-bits)?  Some newbie who apparently doesn't understand the idea of abstraction came along and asked a question that, admittedly, is a bit ranty.  Several people, including myself, tried to come up with useful answers that would help the asker learn and understand... but several other people closed it.

But then something crazy happened.  I went to cast a reopen vote, and there's no reopen link.  The Edit link is grayed out, and hovering over it says that the question is locked.  But there's no "Locked" message anywhere on the question, nor any evidence that a moderator ever looked at it.  (The question was closed by five ordinary users.)  Something appears to be very broken here.

Can someone please fix this?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130116/show-lock-banners-on-rejected-migrations

Comment: Related: [Argumentative users with borderline questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5647/25936)

Answer (score 4):

The question was migrated from Stack Overflow.

If the migration is rejected by the question getting closed as Off Topic or Not a Real Question it's deemed to be a bad migration and the question locked down.

I can unlock it if you think it's salvageable.

Once unlocked you'll be able to cast reopen votes as well as editing it. Once you've finished improving it flag it for moderator attention and we'll look at getting it reopened sooner rather than later.

Comment: Yes, I think it's salvageable, and moreover I think that, being a question from a new user who (presumably) is new to SE and doesn't know the way things work around here, it deserves a bit of leniency as a general principle.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - OK, I've unlocked it. You should be able to cast a reopen vote now.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - editing the rants out would also help :)

Comment: Thanks.  It's still a bug, though, that it would have a "locked" status without displaying it under the question. Can you make bring that to the attention of someone on the team?

Comment: @MasonWheeler - I'm pretty sure it's by design, but I'll double check with the team.

Answer (score 4):

This is sort of an edge-case.

When a migration is [rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations), its answers are deleted on the target site, it is locked, and the reverse happens on the origin site - so right now on SO, [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123889/why-do-data-types-in-computers-exist-if-its-really-all-just-bits) is just marked closed; it could be re-opened, deleted, edited, etc. - unless you check the history, there's no evidence it was ever migrated.

Normally, folks don't *do stuff* to migrated questions after the migration has been rejected. It gets weird. That question now exists in both places. (I will clean this up)

That being said, we probably could do a better job of communicating the state of the question. My preference would be to explicitly state that the question was migrated in *and then rejected*; but we could also just [tack on the normal Locked notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130116/show-lock-banners-on-rejected-migrations); vote for that if you like the idea.